# Window manager view is not allowing to go back

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am adding a view from XML to Window Manager view, Everything is working fine but when i want to go back to previous activity back button is not working even i have removed the added view from window manager inside onBackPressed.

```
manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

    localLayoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
    localLayoutParams.flags = 0x80000000 | localLayoutParams.flags;
    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height =    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    localLayoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness / (float) 255;

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    overlay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    manager.addView(overlay, localLayoutParams);
```

And when i press the back button here is the code to remove the view

```
if(overlay!=null)
 manager.removeView(overlay);
```

Please help me out of this issue.

Comment: Why are u implementing onBackPressed..

Comment: No need for that, But i was thinking that this issue can be resolved by manually removing window manager view but its not working.

Comment: Don't override it and if ur doing, it will not perform its normal function of going back.. Ok then if ur not overriding it then i have to look through ur code once..

Comment: Yes it was not working even if we not implementing the onBackPressed.

Comment: It makes the app hang..And onBack pressed is not called and the error i think is that ur using TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR. Nothing works when this is there

Comment: yes, But the declaring type is essential as it makes the view at top of stack of all views(Even above the status bar). And this is the requirement of my problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Android 5.0. Did you find any solution?